# Preferred way to retrieve data from a template in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm trying to get some data out my templates to, let's say, add an user.

This is what my view object looks like:

```
Ember.View.create({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile( UsersIndexTemplate ),
    addUser: function() {
        var value = $('#my-awesome-input').val();
    }
})
```

In theory I got my value already with jQuery, but is this the preferred way to go?

Comment: I think you should use bindings to solve that. Could you provide more details about the global picture ? (with the definition of the related template and the controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use bindings to bind the values in your template to properties on your view, see an example http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/uuvAp/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="my-template" >
    <!-- bind value of TextField to property username of view -->
    Username: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="view.username"}}
    <button {{action addUser}}>addUser</button>
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'my-template',
    addUser: function(event){
        var username = this.get('username');
        console.log('add user with name: %@'.fmt(username));
    }
}).append();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the available insertNewline for handling the value.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z5SNW/6/