# Ember.js: retrieve random element from a collection

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've a route like this:

```
App.RandomThingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Thing.find("random");
  }
});
```

which takes a trip to `/things/random` API endopoint.

I've also an action in controller:

```
App.RandomThingController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  displayRandomThing: function() {
    return this.content.reload();
  }
});
```

which reloads the random thing in the template.

I'm just starting with Ember.js (or any MVC front-end framework) and I've few doubts / questions:

1. First of all: is this a correct way to do things (`this.content.reload()`)?
2. My API endpoint accepts `old_thing` parameter which allows to fetch random thing different than the currently displayed one: `/things/random?old_thing=Something`. What is the most idiomatic / correct way to implement this in Ember.js? How to pass this `old_thing` to `find()` and `reload()`? Should I use a view for that as suggested here: [Preferred way to retrieve data from a template in EmberJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138389/preferred-way-to-retrieve-data-from-a-template-in-emberjs) ?

I had a hard time trying to find some docs regarding `ember-data` (everything feels outdated).

Answer (score 0):

1 - I would rather reload the content in this way in the controller:

```
reloadContent: function(){
    this.set('content', App.Thing.find("random"));
}
```

2 - if you want to pass parameters to your GET (assuming you are using the RESTAdapter) you can pass them in by using an hash.

```
App.Thing.find({old_thing: 'oldThing');
```

But there is something 'fishy' here. Model.find expects an id, or an hash. Your 'random' kinda feels like neither.

I don't know if you can send in parameters when you spesify an Id, as you spesify with your "random". That kinda feels wrong since you have spesified that you want to get a single item, but are sending in a hash as well to filter for items. (doh that is not ur intention)

Comment: I understand that Ember.js is not suited for such task (I'm not complaining, just stating the fact)... How would you handle it then?

Answer (score 0):

I came looking for an answer to this problem and ended up here. I needed to find a random record for my model, and wasn't sure how to call call the store's find method.

After looking in the ember-data source I discovered that passing an object into the find method switches the store from findById to findQuery.

That made me think that a decent way to call find for a single random object may be:

`App.Thing.find({random:true, old_thing: 'oldThing', limit:1});`

These will be converted to query parameters, which you will then need to modify your API 'Thing' endpoint to accept.

`api/thing?random=true&old_thing=oldThing&limit=1`

Allowing the random flag and limit to be passed in as parameters means you don't have to messy up you API with extra routes for finding random records.

I'm not sure if this is the most idiomatic way to go about it, but it's what I've chosen to go with.

EDIT:

Just a side note, if you query like this, your API combined with Ember Data should return an array with one element. Now, because the call is made asynchronously, the element won't be defined immediately after calling "find", so you'll have to add an observer to update your controller's content once the item has loaded.

Something like this, on my track controller:

```
, randomiseTrack: function(){
        var _this = this
        var currentTrackId = this.get('content.id')
        var loadingTrackList = App.Track.find({
            random:true, 
            current_track_id: currentTrackId, 
            limit: 1
        });
        loadingTrackList.addObserver("isLoaded", function(){
            _this.set('content', loadingTrackList.materializedObjectAt(0));
        });
}
```