# Ember.js adds elements to collection "magically"

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Question related somewhat to: [Ember.js: retrieve random element from a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621481/ember-js-retrieve-random-element-from-a-collection)

I've two routes: `randomThing` route and `things` route.

The former displays a... random thing from an API (`GET /things/random`) (there is a button to "Get another random thing"), the latter: displays all things: (`GET /things`).

The problem is that EVERY TIME when I click on `Get another random thing` and new thing is displayed and I go to `recipes` route this newly displayed random thing is added to the collection...

Action to get random thing performs a `find("random")` as suggested in related question and sets `this.content` to this value.

What is wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I'm using `ember-data` and my route is like this:

```
App.ThingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Thing.find();
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you using ember-data ? If so, what is your `model` function in the `/things` route ? I believe this is due to the identity map, when another `App.Thing` is fetched, it is automatically added to the `App.Thing.find()`

Comment: @louiscoquio: question updated

Comment: Do you have `id` properties set on **all** the returned data? In theory, if an `id` returned from random is already in the collection, then it shouldn't be appended to the collection.

Comment: @Wildhoney: yes, they just come from different endpoint: class the same, id the same, name the same (basically all attributes).

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that EVERY TIME when I click on Get another random thing and new thing is displayed and I go to recipes route this newly displayed random thing is added to the collection...

This is expected behavior. `App.Thing.find()` does not simply query the api and return results. Instead find() returns an array containing of all Things ember knows about. It includes objects returned by past calls to find(), objects created client-side via App.Thing.createRecord(), and of course individual objects queried via `App.Thing.find('random')`. After returning this array, find() and kicks off another API call and if that returns additional records they are pushed onto the array.

> What is wrong here?

It does not sound like anything is wrong per-se. If you want to prevent random things from showing up in the ThingsRoute, you'll need to change that route's model to be a filter instead of just returning every Thing. For example:

```
App.ThingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    //Kick off query to fetch records from the server (async)
    App.Thing.find();

    //Return only non-random posts by applying a client-side filter to the posts array
    return App.Thing.filter(function(hash) {
      if (!hash.get('name').match(/random/)) { return true; }
    });
  }
});
```

See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iyijaf/1/edit) for a working example

To learn more about filters I recommend reading the ember-data [store-model-filter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/store_model_filter_test.js) integration test

Comment: Thank you @michael-grassotti. Could you elaborate? What do you mean by "filter"?

Comment: Sure - updating my answer to include an example of a "filter"

Comment: I believe the problem lingers somewhere else: `things` route displays ALL things. `randomThing` route displays one random thing (fetched from the backend API, its name doesn't match "random"). This random thing is the same class as the all other things - why does Ember pushes to the collection the same object (all "visible" parameters like `id` and `name` are the same).